# How can I generate eclipse makefiles from the command line

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, makefile

I have multiple projects that I work on through Emacs. The only time I ever open eclipse is to regenerate make files after I have created or removed files.

I have no experience in working with make and would be worried about modifying them by hand since other people rely on these files.

Does eclipse just rely on some other tool that I can call myself?
or
Is it possible to tell eclipse to do this from the command line?

Comment: May be this https://emacswiki.org/emacs/CompileCommand help.

Comment: This is just setting a make command and running it with compile-command. I need a way to have eclipse generate a make file from the command line to be used with compile-command essentially